# Symfony3 FosUserBundle mail confirm after registration

Tags: php, symfony, email, fosuserbundle

After the registration of a new account, I have the following message:

> Un e-mail a été envoyé à l'adresse name@mail.com. Il contient un lien d'activation sur lequel il vous faudra cliquer afin d'activer votre compte.

It means that a mail was send to name@mail.com But when I check, there is no mail.

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: dbsym
database_user: root
database_password: ######
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: mail.smtp2go.com
mailer_user: ######
mailer_password: #######
secret: #########
```

**config.yml**

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
from_email:
    address: "%mailer_user%"
    sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled: true
        template: '@FOSUser\Registration\email.txt.twig'
    form:
        type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
profile:
    form:
        type: AppBundle\Form\ProfileType
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: Maybe you have something like :
`swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true`
In your config.yml or config_dev.yml

Comment: nothing change if i add that: swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery:  true config_dev.yml

Comment: the message was not seed to my mail.

Comment: There are a lot reasons why your mail will not be delivered. Check your spam, check the smpt port to use, double check if your code really tries to send the email, check your credentials. Some provider have additional restrictions, for example the from must contain the domain name. think wide and you will be able to solve it. Also try an non HTML email without attachments first

Comment: No doesn't add `disable_delivery: true` obviously it's for disable delivery exactly the opposite of what you want... I just ask if it's not already disable in your configuration.

Comment: I already check the spam. As you say, it may be that the problem is other. I'll keep looking ...

Comment: Did you try to add `mailer_port` in your swiftmailer config or in your parameters.yml ?
`mailer_port: 1025`

Comment: Yes! But its not walking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I have done is type the command in console swiftmailer: email: send in the console to test mail sending and its working. Then I register a new user, I check and see it the mail.

> console swiftmailer:email:send ...